# FriendlyID Korean slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

When I add article in Korean language with title e.g.: `신품`

FriendlyID gem creates blank slug and url is like `/8` ... so this is ID. Look at this link: `http://www.srecipe.kr.com/articles/8`

Other languages work.

How can I get url which is mapped to latin letters like /this-is-url from `신품` ?

Comment: It was answered? I don't think so! That was marked as off topic and force closed. PLEASE!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like all of these permalink solutions, friendly ID uses the `parameterize` method to convert a string into a URL safe string. like so:

```
require 'active_support/all'
puts "Oh Hai There".parameterize
=> oh-hai-there
```

The problem comes in when you use non ASCII strings, which parameterize replaces with an empty string, causing your problem:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'active_support/all'
puts "신품".parameterize
=>
```

ActiveSupport provides a way to change non ASCII strings to a close approximate via the `transliterate` method.

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'active_support/all'
include ActiveSupport::Inflector

puts transliterate("Ærøskøbing")
=> AEroskobing
```

But, if it doesn't know about a character, it'll default to ??

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'active_support/all'
include ActiveSupport::Inflector

puts transliterate "신품"
=> ??
```

But, you can tell transliterate how to handle the characters. So in a Rails model

```
# Store the transliterations in locales/en.yml
en:
  i18n:
    transliterate:
      rule:
        신: "abc"
        품: "def"

puts transliterate "신품"
=> "abcdef"
```

So, you can use `transliterate(title).parameterize` instead of just parameterize. And if you get the korean alphabet into transliterate section, you're close to golden.

Comment: I forgot to wrap the resulting rule in quotes:

I18n::InvalidLocaleData: can not load translations from config/locales/en.yml: #<Psych::SyntaxError: (config/locales/en.yml): did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character while scanning an anchor

Answer (score 2):

Not tried these yet but I'm going to:

- https://github.com/makimoto/romaji
- https://github.com/aelaa/hangul
- https://github.com/janx/ruby-pinyin

I'll report back when I've tried them.

Comment: Where's the report?

Comment: Fair comment. 2+ years later I now can't remember what my conclusions were. Do you think I should delete the reply or leave the list of repos there in case they are helpful to someone?

Comment: The romaji repo was helpful to me! Thank you for the link!