# Rails: FriendlyID Japanese slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, friendly-url

I have a blog app that use Friendly_id gem and but when I use Japanese Character in the title and go to article show i have a url like this `http://www.blog.com/articles/8`. but i want to get url which is mapped to japanese letters or latin letters, how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

So there is this solution has been suggested: [FriendlyID Korean slugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855883/friendlyid-korean-slugs)

however I tend to prefer a solution with : http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/unidecode

```
gem 'unidecode'
# ...
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :nickname_ascii, use: :slugged
# using gem unidecode
def nickname_ascii
  nickname.to_ascii
end
```

Good enough for kana but quite bad for Kanji